# Follow buffer in emacs, a la tail -f or less +F

Tags: emacs, reload

I would like to analyze a log file in `emacs` while it is growing. Is it possible to have a buffer follow a file? It is not needed that the file be editable (which raises all sort of questions): read-only mode would suffice.

My problem in more detail is this:

1. I open the logfile en emacs
2. I am looking for some error in the logfile
3. I realize it is not there because the buffer is not up-to-date
4. I have to manually reload the buffer (`revert-buffer`)

I would like to improve this workflow by letting `emacs` do the reloading automagically. Maybe a periodic `revert-buffer`? How to setup such periodic reloading?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the `auto-revert-tail-mode` to do this... I have following in my `~/.emacs` (just to convenience...):

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.log\\'" . auto-revert-mode))
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it pays off to just `ctr-x-h-<tab>` and then search. Who would have thought that the emacs developers would have already implemented exactly what I am looking for, and would have used such obvious name? :)

Comment: It's better expect that almost everything is implemented for Emacs, and only missing piece is the name of the package ;-)

Comment: That variable is for major modes only.  Putting a minor mode there is asking for UB.

Comment: @AlexanderShukaev the `auto-mode-alist` was mentioned as a setting that I have in the my config file - just an example...

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried using the `auto-revert-tail-mode`? - Invoked with `M-x auto-revert-tail-mode`

Answer (score 5):

Lee Hinman wrote an amazingly detailed and helpful writeup about working with log files in Emacs using `auto-revert-tail-mode` at [Writequit.org](https://writequit.org/articles/working-with-logs-in-emacs.html) called, well, "[Working with log files in Emacs](https://writequit.org/articles/working-with-logs-in-emacs.html)".

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the excellent **itail** tool from which can be installed from the MELPA repository. You invoke it as follows:-

```
`M-x` itail
```

You can use **itail** with local files as well as remote files using TRAMP. More information about **itail** can be found [here](http://github.com/re5et/itail).